# How to assign to mvar with case syntax?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'am asking if i can add same think like that :

```
if maVar == "false" then maVar = "" else maVar = maVar
```

in tmy code haskell (yesod)

```
let maVar= unpack $ case Map.lookup "maVarSession" sess of
        Just a -> a
        Nothing -> "Nothing"
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Remember that no one else knows what you're trying to do, so you'll need to be as precise as possible.

Comment: what i need is where maVar = "false" it become maVar = ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `maVar` is imutable and it is `String` always.

In Haskell there aren't any `false`. It has `False`.

You could do next:

```
let maVar = ...
in
  let maVarNew = if maVar == "Nothing" then "" else maVar
  in
```

Comment: my "false" is string too

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're attempting to assign a new value to `maVar`. This *does not make sense* in Haskell, because Haskell doesn't really have mutable variables,* and you're getting a syntax error because the parser sees `=` in a position which does not accept declarations.

Instead, you can declare a new value (we can name it whatever, but let's call it `maVar'`), defined `maVar' = if maVar == "false" then "" else maVar`.

Then, we can write

```
let maVar = unpack $ case Map.lookup "maVarSession" sess of
        Just a -> a
        Nothing -> "Nothing"
    maVar' = if maVar == "false" then "" else maVar
  [...]
```

Guards can be also used to write the new declaration (perhaps more clearly, possibly not) as

```
    maVar'
      | maVar == "false" = ""
      | otherwise = maVar
```

It would probably be a good idea to make sure you understand what exactly you're doing, however; perhaps read some introductory texts on Haskell to understand purity and how Haskell works differently from languages you might be familiar with.

* You can have a mutable cell, but you really have to ask specifically for it—you can't easily do it by accident.